# Entity manager has not been injected:is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?

Tags: spring, aspectj

I'm trying write a simple spring rest web service, since I'm not familiar with maven(and because maven usually can't et things done--connection issue), so I'm trying ant build now. Now, the build is ok and the service can run. But if the persistent function is triggered, it will prompt:

```
 01:48:39 Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'uncaughtException'; model is {exception=java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)} -org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)
    at com.books.domain.UserInfo.entityManager(UserInfo.java:96)
    at com.books.domain.UserInfo.findUserByNamePassword(UserInfo.java:157)
    at com.books.web.UserController.register(UserController.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
```

My ant build.xml:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source ">
    <!--<javac srcdir="${src}" 
    debug="on"
    destdir="${build}" 
    classpathref="compile.classpath"
    includeantruntime="false"/>-->
    <iajc source ="1.6" target="1.6" sourceroots="src/main/java" destDir="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes" showweaveinfo="true" verbose="true">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
            <path refid="aspectj.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
    </iajc>
</target>
```

My applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "and because maven usually can't et things done" hahahaha, you made my day. Are you aware that thousands of software projects use maven all the time, all pover the world? I have not worked in a single project over the last 5 years that wasn't built with maven.

Comment: Hi Sean, any idea to help? I just mean my network is bad and maven need to download too many artifacts from its central repository. By using ant, I can download them manually (using multi-thread download tool) so it's fast.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution :

This is the correct iajc task

```
<iajc source ="1.6" target="1.6" sourceroots="src/main/java" destDir="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes" showweaveinfo="true" verbose="true">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
        <path refid="aspectj.classpath"/>
    </classpath>
    <aspectpath>
         <pathelement location="${workdir}/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aspects-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
    </aspectpath>
</iajc>
```

Comment: HERE is the working solution! I am sorry that I can only upvote this a single time! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue by using ROO and maven pom. Too less info on how to use Ant build.

Comment: I've made a maven-free ant build of a roo project possible, if somebody wants a solution, I could write one.

Answer (score 1):

Considering switching to Roo is not really a solution but a workaround, I want to share my experiences about this issue.

There are 2 things you need to check:

1. You need to compile your classes via aspectj. Maven aspectj plugin provides this requirement.
2. Your entity class must be annotated with `@Configurable`